# jQuery not selector with [name] selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following jQuery selector to select inputs by a specific name:

```
find('input[name=sn_cmd]')
```

now I want to add another selector to it to ignore any input whose id is "send".

What should I do?

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/not-selector

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `:not` selector,

```
find('input[name=sn_cmd]:not("#send")')
```

or you can do the same thing using the `.not()` function.

```
find('input[name=sn_cmd]').not('#send')
```

Comment: though now I prefer .not()

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as well:

```
find('input[name=sn_cmd]').not('#send');
```